# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: dagger/Provides.class

Tags: android, sdk, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2

When I sync the project everything is ok, but when I try to run I've got this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: dagger/Provides.class

Here is my app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "appID"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.5'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.5'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta4'

    compile('com.sumup:merchant-sdk:1.61.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}
```

If I run without   `compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.5'` it is success compiled.. please help.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the answer to your own question! You mention "the question can be closed", but I think your question is valid and your answer is useful, and that future readers may have additional useful information to contribute. Please edit your answer out of the question and into a [self-answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), which you can then properly accept to mark the question as done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

It [looks like](https://github.com/sumup/sumup-android-sdk/issues/12) sumup sdk is not compatible with dagger 2.+.

So I have downgrade to dagger 1.+ and it is working ok. No other issues appeared until now.

Comment: Thanks for figuring this out.  I commented on the bug with how they might resolve the issue, so with any luck it won't be a problem for long.

Answer (score 1):

Before downgrading, would you consider trying replacing `compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.5'` with the following:

```
compile ('com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0') {
    exclude group: 'javax.inject'
}
```

This will exclude the duplicate class.

Comment: have you tested it?

Comment: I had a similar problem with a duplicate `Provides` class in `Espresso` that would not play well with Dagger 2. The code I quoted above solved the problem in our project but your mileage may vary.

Comment: from their  [documentation](https://github.com/sumup/sumup-android-sdk/issues/12), there is no workaround with dagger 2. I have test it with your version but it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue when we switched to Dagger.

We use same package names in different artifacts for the @Component and @Module classes and the Dagger generated the same `Dagger...Component.java` file in every artifact where we use the same package.

After we moved the components into unique packages in every artifacts, the problem was solved with it.